# Shiny getsymbols works but no column name containing "close"

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I am working on a school project that needs to run some code base on trading rules. However, those codes run perfectly in R but not Shiny. I try many possible solutions but still fail to do so, like Add-on QMAO. To streamline, the codes here are part of the code of my school project.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
ui <- fluidPage(

      textInput("symb", "Stock Name", "AAPL"),
      
      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     "Date range",
                     start = "2020-01-01",
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      actionButton("GO","GO"),

      tableOutput("table")
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{

    getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)
    
    price <- Cl(input$symb) #this code failed, no column name containing "close". However, I tried to check getSymbols working or not by outputing the stock data table. It works. Delect this code can run with no error.
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
      data()
    })
)
```

For some reason, I am not able to use Close when the Close does exist.

PS: Here is the code that works in R. I replace MSFT by input$symb.

```
price <- Cl(MSFT)
r <- price/Lag(price) - 1
delta<-0.005
signal <-c(NA) # first signal is NA


for (i in 2: length(Cl(MSFT))){
  if (r[i] > delta){
    signal[i]<- 1
  } else if (r[i]< -delta){
    signal[i]<- -1
  } else
    signal[i]<- 0
}

signal<-reclass(signal,Cl(MSFT))


trade1 <- Lag(signal)
ret1<-dailyReturn(MSFT)*trade1
names(ret1) <- 'Naive'
charts.PerformanceSummary(ret1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current code, if we want to extract object, use `get` on the character object name and also, use `auto.assign = TRUE`

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
    
    getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = TRUE)
    
    price <- Cl(get(input$symb))#this code failed, no column name containing "close". However, I tried to check getSymbols working or not by outputing the stock data table. It works. Delect this code can run with no error.
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Or else can be assigned to a new object

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
    
    tmp <- getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)
    
    price <- Cl(tmp)#this code failed, no column name containing "close". However, I tried to check getSymbols working or not by outputing the stock data table. It works. Delect this code can run with no error.
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]